# Using variables in headings in HTML

Tags: html

I'm working on a project for a class, and I have a login page (with a username and password) that opens another page. Is there a way that I can customize the heading on that page to say "Hello *username*"?

```
<center> <h2>Hello <script> name = document.getElementById('email').value; document.write(name); </script> ! </h2></center>
```

Im sure there has to be a real simple way to do something like this? I've been looking but haven't had any luck, thanks.

Comment: To clarify, the login page doesn't open another page, it simply hides the login div and shows another div.

Comment: Is the user's name stored somewhere in the HTML on the page? If so, show us please.

Comment: DACrosby Thanks for the help, I actually just figured it out. It was actually much simplier than I thought. I added an id to the header, and edited that id in a function as soon as the login button is hit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- One way of doing is store the username in the cookie on the login page 

    $cookie_username = "username";
    $cookie_value = "xyz";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

- read the cookie on the second page 



  if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_username])) {

       hello  $_COOKIE[$cookie_username] ;

    }
```

Comment: I actually need to use cookies somewhere else in this project also, if you know of a good article explaining them, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/set-cookies.shtml  ... This article explains the complete stuffs on cookies, .

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function personalizeHeader(){
        name = document.getElementById('email2').value;
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
    </script>
```

---

```
<div id="Login" style="display:show">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    username 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="Text" placeholder="email" name="email2" id="email2"></br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    Password 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="Text"  name="password" id="password"></br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <button onclick="showForm();">Login </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

---

```
<center> <h2 id="header">  </h2></center>
```